# How to get an element through amp script by using DOM accessor

Tags: javascript, ampscript

Trying to get the element through DOM accessor in amp-script

Tried to get element by classanme,id and queryselector but couldnot get element

```
var blogs =  document.getElementById('home-blog-cards');
```

Expected the element but got some other data

Answer (score 2):

when using amp-script, you can get the elements inside `amp-script` tag, because `querySelector` is currently partially supported.

Check the official documentation: [amp-script docs](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/)